# How to find Apple App Group shared directory

Tags: ios, swift, ios-app-extension

We are currently developing an iOS10 app, including "Messages Extension".

To share CoreDatas persistant `store.sqlite` inbetween App and Extension, we are using a shared "Apple App Group" directory, which is working fine.

Now we have to get our hands on the store for debug reasons and are unable to find the directory. The Apps container directories are completely empty, which makes sense. But how to download our database? Do we have to somehow copy it programmatically to a reachable place?

**To sum it up:**

- We already use CoreData which stores model.sqlite in our shared directory.
- Everything is up and running.
- What we want to archive is to download the database to our computer.

Without a shared directory we can simply download the App container from the device, using Xcode->Devices. But as we do use a shared directory, the .sqlite database is not within the container.

**Question:**
How can we download the .sqlite database from the device to our computer?

Comment: It would be helpful to see some code.  For instance, how do you know that the shared container is indeed empty?  Did you look inside NSFileManager.defaultManager().containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier("group.etc.etc.")?

Comment: The shared container is not empty. The Apps container is.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**EDIT on 2018-10-12:** Updated code for **Swift 4.x (Xcode 10)**.  (Older version retained for reference.)

**In Swift 4.x:**

```
let sharedContainerURL :URL? = FileManager.default.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: "group.etc.etc")
// replace "group.etc.etc" above with your App Group's identifier
NSLog("sharedContainerURL = \(String(describing: sharedContainerURL))")
if let sourceURL :URL = sharedContainerURL?.appendingPathComponent("store.sqlite") {
    if let destinationURL :URL = FileManager().urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first?.appendingPathComponent("copyOfStore.sqlite") {
        try! FileManager().copyItem(at: sourceURL, to: destinationURL)
    }
}
```

**In older version of Swift (probably Swift 2.x):**

```
let sharedContainerURL :NSURL? = NSFileManager.defaultManager().containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier("group.etc.etc")  // replace "group.etc.etc" with your App Group's identifier
NSLog("sharedContainerURL = \(sharedContainerURL)")
if let sourceURL :NSURL = sharedContainerURL?.URLByAppendingPathComponent("store.sqlite")
{
  if let destinationURL :NSURL = NSFileManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)[0].URLByAppendingPathComponent("copyOfStore.sqlite")
  {
    try! NSFileManager().copyItemAtURL(sourceURL, toURL: destinationURL)
  }
}
```

Something like the above will get a file from the app group's shared container to the app's Documents directory.  From there, you could use Xcode > Window > Devices to get it to your computer.

You could also use iTunes file sharing to retrieve the file from the app's Documents directory after setting `UIFileSharingEnabled` to `YES` in the `Info.plist` file, but bear in mind that this will expose the directory's contents to the user as well.  Should be okay for development/debugging purposes, though.

Comment: I am aware of how to reach it programatically. Accept answer anyway. Thanks.

Comment: I was dealing with the same issue using a shared Realm Database. There is no other way I know of to access a shared container from a device. This is spot on, even two years later (though the Swift syntax has changed).

Comment: @Zig  Thanks for the heads-up.  I have updated the code to bring it in line with the most recent version of Swift.

Comment: I am using the same way..file is copied.. but content is not being copied from group container to document container.